# Is base::noquote the accepted way to program using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyeval

I have a function that takes a dataframe and must gather it based on varying columns depending on the dataset passed in. So I need a way to tell the `gather()` function which columns need to be gathered dynamically. I am curious if passing the columns in as strings to the function and then using `noqoute()` is the best way to do this. The code currently works but I feel I may be missing something that could eventually break the code. Here is my code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Data will always take a wide format similar to this
raw_dat <- tibble(id = 1:30, 
       garbage = letters[runif(30, min = 1, max = 26)], 
       group1 = runif(30, min = 200, max = 5000),
       group2 = runif(30, min = 200, max = 5000),
       group3 = runif(30, min = 200, max = 5000),
       group4 = runif(30, min = 200, max = 5000),
       group5 = runif(30, min = 200, max = 5000),
       garbage2 = letters[runif(30, min = 1, max = 26)],
       garbage3 = letters[runif(30, min = 1, max = 26)])

raw_dat
#> # A tibble: 30 x 9
#>       id garbage group1 group2 group3 group4 group5 garbage2 garbage3
#>    <int> <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
#>  1     1 n        2234.  4852.  4745.  4381.  3331. v        l       
#>  2     2 y        3749.  2084.  2555.  3445.  3288. y        e       
#>  3     3 x        1796.  1088.  2300.  2425.  2124. u        j       
#>  4     4 m        3912.   646.   497.  4669.  2532. g        c       
#>  5     5 y         344.   559.  1989.  4459.  4139. x        m       
#>  6     6 k        4671.  1215.  1568.  3802.  1536. y        p       
#>  7     7 g        3117.  3797.   391.  3192.  2695. t        l       
#>  8     8 x         230.  1277.  4450.  3437.  1235. c        o       
#>  9     9 x         491.   871.  4559.  4010.  4478. b        r       
#> 10    10 l         292.   701.   903.  2308.  4573. e        e       
#> # … with 20 more rows

# This number will change by varying datasets and user entry
input_groups <- names(raw_dat)[3:7]

# My function does more than this but I am concerned with making this part dynamic
compute_values <- function(df, input_g){
  df %>% 
    gather(key = "input_group", value = "input_value", noquote(input_g))
}

compute_values(raw_dat, input_groups)
#> # A tibble: 150 x 6
#>       id garbage garbage2 garbage3 input_group input_value
#>    <int> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>             <dbl>
#>  1     1 n       v        l        group1            2234.
#>  2     2 y       y        e        group1            3749.
#>  3     3 x       u        j        group1            1796.
#>  4     4 m       g        c        group1            3912.
#>  5     5 y       x        m        group1             344.
#>  6     6 k       y        p        group1            4671.
#>  7     7 g       t        l        group1            3117.
#>  8     8 x       c        o        group1             230.
#>  9     9 x       b        r        group1             491.
#> 10    10 l       e        e        group1             292.
#> # … with 140 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I think the recommended / tidyeval way is going to rely on `tidyselect` to get columns. Or take a set of bare column names and use `!!!quos(...)`. How exactly to do it depends on how the user input would be coming in--in your example you're selecting columns by their position in `names`, but `dplyr`-type functions would often use bare column names. Which do you think you'll need?

Comment: @camille I'm making this script for users who don't have much experience in R and if they could just specify the column numbers of their input_parameters that would make it really easy for them.

Comment: I think ideally they would change the header names to include something like `input_p_group1` that way I could utilize `contains()` but I don't have that kind of leverage yet haha

Comment: @camille The `...` can be passed directly to other functions, no need to quote and splice.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean with changing the header names. If you want to take positions, you can use `!!!names(.)[pos]` as the column selection in `gather`. `pos` could be the function argument of positions

Comment: @camille but I essentially can just do `!!!input_g` wouldn't that be the same thing?Then I wouldn't need to change the user code `input_groups <- names(raw_dat)[3:7]`. Would you say that is more accepted way than `noquote()`?

Comment: The `noquote()` function only affects how strings are printed to the console. It does not create symbols that can be used with lazy evaluation -- it's not the right function for this task at all. Your function here would work just fine without the `noquote()` because `gather()` takes strings and you are passing strings. See this guide for the right way to program with dplyr: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: @MrFlick Upvote because I thought I had tried just passing in a string and I got an error. I just tried it though, and it worked out. Although I have read that link, I even referenced it in the title so my question was an attempt to clarify the content in the article.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we don't have to tell which columns to transpose if we follow the below approach with `pivot_longer`

```r
library(tidyr)

raw_dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(id,garbage,garbage2,garbage3), names_to = 'input_group', values_to = 'input_value')
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 150 × 6
      id garbage garbage2 garbage3 input_group input_value
   <int> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>             <dbl>
 1     1 y       i        l        group1            2313.
 2     1 y       i        l        group2            3961.
 3     1 y       i        l        group3            2196.
 4     1 y       i        l        group4            3047.
 5     1 y       i        l        group5            2423.
 6     2 e       b        p        group1            1996.
 7     2 e       b        p        group2             520.
 8     2 e       b        p        group3             990.
 9     2 e       b        p        group4            3346.
10     2 e       b        p        group5            4034.
# ℹ 140 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```